# How do i require a helper file in presenter - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, presenter

I have a rails application. I need to use a helper within a presenter class. I used
`require 'number_helper'` and used a method 'test' from 'number_helper'. It is giving me an error that `'undefined method 'test''`.

How do I require a helper file in a presenter class. If I use `'include NumberHelper'` it works. what is the wrong with my usage of 'require'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails, Helpers are `modules` which are directly accessible in immediate view but in order to access them in a controller you need use `include` directive to specify the module explicitly.

In your case, `test` is an instance method. If you wish to access it in a class then either you need to include the module as specified above.

BUT if you want to access it using `require 'number_helper'` then define `test` as a class method(`def self.test`) and access it in controller as `NumberHelper::test`.